# how to log out a user after 15 minutes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

Using MVC with orchard 1.7 for security/test purpose I have set the system to log out any user after 1 min in the webcofig file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="1"/>
</authentication>
```

This does not seem to work, as after a few mins if I start navigating through the back end of the site, it works fine. Isnt this meant to log me out after 1 m? which means I cant view the back end.

I have then used the [Authorize] attribute above all my functions in my project.
However, this doesnt appear to do much, someone suggested deleting the mappings.bin file in the 'sites' folder.

All I want to do, is to logout the user after 15 mins, if the user tries to re-fresh or go back after 15m, then will be navigated to the login page.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong

Comment: Have you checked to verify that the user is not getting a cached page after the formsauth timeout?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in Orchard.Framework -> Security -> Providers -> FormsAuthenticationService, you can change how long a user is signed in for in the SignIn method. So you should probably overwrite this service with your own if you don't want to edit the core.